# conflicts with another tag that has the same ID

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I'm having a problem updating an XML file

```
Found data binding error(s):

[databinding] {"msg":"\u003cRelativeLayout id\u003d\u0027@+id/rlSearch\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\home_fragment_new.xml","pos":[{"line0":105,"col0":20,"line1":140,"col1":37}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"\u003ccom.pets.igloopet.utils.CustomEditText id\u003d\u0027@+id/IVsearch\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\home_fragment_new.xml","pos":[{"line0":123,"col0":29,"line1":137,"col1":69}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"\u003cRelativeLayout id\u003d\u0027@+id/rlSearch\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\home_fragment_new.xml","pos":[{"line0":167,"col0":20,"line1":200,"col1":36}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"\u003ccom.pets.igloopet.utils.CustomEditText id\u003d\u0027@+id/IVsearch\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\home_fragment_new.xml","pos":[{"line0":184,"col0":28,"line1":197,"col1":68}]}
```

My code
[Full code](https://codepen.io/okwvkcmz/pen/oNomKNX)

I tried the following

- gradlew assembleDebug
- tools: viewBindingIgnore = "true"
- File> Invalidate Caches / Restart> Invalidate and Restart

**Unfortunately nothing helps**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the Api version with your emulator, for me it worked

Comment: It helped me a lot, what else helped me was to delete the other ID which is also in the comment

Answer (score 1):

Restarted Mac after Invalidated Cache is resolve this issue

Comment: For a new convert to Mac, this was exactly what I needed. All the usual Windows tricks didn't help with whatever was keeping the files broken on Mac.